# if(!session_id()) not working as expected?

Tags: php, session

Here's my code;

```
if(!session_id())
{ 
session_set_cookie_params(2592000, "/", ".domain.com", false);
session_name("VALCODE");
session_start();
} else { 
echo "Testing 123";
}
```

What I had in mind was to see see if session_id() and thus a session was already set, if not, set start a session, if so, echo Testing 123.

What happens is that it sets a session when first loaded, however when reloaded it doesn't echo "Testing 123", so as far as I know it does nothing.

Could someone please point me in the right direction for running checks to see if there's already an active session, or comment on my code and such?

Any comments, info or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to [start the session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) first.

Comment: I might be off point here, but it's just come to me; will session_set_cookie_params and such be ignored if there's already a session? In otherwords, this script is designed to set a session if there already isn't one active, as I was under the impression that if I had session_set_cookie_params(), session_name(), session_start() etc on a sites homepage, and then re-called them on a sub-page, it would overwrite the already existing credentials? Does it just carry them through?

Comment: A `session` is a `session` is a `session`. Don't overthink it. PHP provides all of the session functionality you need in this case, you don't need to create one. Just call `session_start()`.

Comment: Thanks. It kind of figures, seeing as I couldn't find a thread or article anywhere relating to checking whether or not a session was set, so that it wouldn't overwrite by setting a new one. Again, thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write:

```
session_start()
```

before anything. if you want to see whether ant session is set or not then you should simply write:

```
if(count($_SESSION)>0){}
```

and if you want to check for particular session then ..

```
if($_SESSION['session_name']!='' && isset($_SESSION['session_name'])){}
```

these are alternatives that you can use ...

Comment: I like `if (empty($_SESSION))` better than the `count` method